# cakephp: login link not taking me to login page instead it is taking me to loginRedirect page

Tags: cakephp, cookies, redirect

My login link on register page is not taking me to login page. Instead it is taking me to report_card page which is the loginRedirect page.

In beforeFilter i've set autoRedirect to false coz' i'm setting cookies in login function and then i'm setting $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());

Can someone please help me? thanks in advance.

my code:

register.ctp

```
   <?php
         echo $this->Html->link('Sign Up','/merry_parents/signup',array()).' for new user |'.$this->Html->link('Login','/merry_parents/login',array()).' for existing user';
    ?>
```

app_controller.php

```
   class AppController extends Controller {


var $components=array('Auth','Session','Cookie');

function beforeFilter(){
  if (isset($this->Auth)){
        $this->Auth->userModel='MerryParent';
        $this->Auth->loginAction=array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'login');
                    //var_dump($this->data);

        $this->Auth->loginRedirect=array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'report_card');
        $this->Auth->allow('signup','login','logout','display');
        $this->Auth->authorize='controller';
                  }
   else
        $this->Session->setFlash('Auth has not been set');  

}

function isAuthorized(){
    return true;
}
```

merry_parents_controller.php

```
      <?php
       class MerryParentsController extends AppController{

var $name='MerryParents';
var $helpers=array('Html','Form');

function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect=false;
            parent::beforeFilter();

}


function report_card(){
}

function register(){

}

function login(){

    if ($this->Auth->user()){
        if (!empty($this->data)){
                    $this->MerryParent->id=$this->MerryParent->field('id',array(
                                        'MerryParent.username'=>$this->data['MerryParent']['username'],
                                        'MerryParent.password'=>$this->data['MerryParent']['password']
                                        )
                                    );
                    echo 'id: '.$this->MerryParent->id;
                    $this->Cookie->write('MerryParent.id',$this->MerryParent->id,false,0);
                    $this->set('id',$this->Cookie->read('MerryParent.id'));


            }
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }

}
```

report_card.ctp

```
    <?php
      var_dump($this->data);

 echo 'HALLO';
 if (isset($id))
    echo $id;
 else
       echo 'id has not been set';

      ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was when I clicked on login link for the first time, login link displays fine. But, the next time i click on login link again, login page doesn't display, instead report_card page (ie. the login redirect page) displays. The reason is, i didn't have a logout button anywhere on my webpage, so the user was logged on all the time. Thanks.

in register function of merry_parents_controller.php

```
  function register(){
    $this->set('id',$this->Session->read('Auth.MerryParent.id'));
}
```

in register.ctp

```
   <?php

        if (isset($id)){
      echo $this->Html->link('Logout',
            array('controller'=>'merry_parents','action'=>'logout'),array());

        }
       else{
    echo $this->Html->link('Sign Up','/merry_parents/signup',array()).' for new user |'.
        $this->Html->link('Login','/merry_parents/login',array()).' for existing user';
    }

    ?>
```

now, login and logout works fine.